# maya/python modify modelPanel layout and behaviour

Tags: python, maya

I'm working on my first script in python. It should be just a 2 tabs script, on one tab there will be the character picker, on the second tab there should be a camera view with the face GUI.

I'd like to get rid of the red circled menu (which you can see here http://postimg.org/image/fozvc010x/) and lock the view in that way, forbidding zoom and pan.

I tried to search on the maya help but it is not very clear for me.

I also attach the code responsible for that view.

```
FacialGUI = cmds.formLayout()



FacialPanel = cmds.modelPanel(camera = "facial_cam")
cmds.formLayout(FacialGUI, e=True,
                            attachForm=[
                                (FacialPanel, "top", 0),
                                (FacialPanel, "left", 0), 
                                (FacialPanel, "bottom", 0), 
                                (FacialPanel, "right", 0)
                            ]) 


cmds.setParent( '..' )
```

Thanks,
Daniele!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the red circled menu, in command *modelPanel* try to set menuBarVisible flag to False

```
FacialPanel = cmds.modelPanel(camera = "facial_cam", mbv=False)
```

With the command `mel.eval("ToggleModelEditorBars")` you can toggle editor bars' visibility.

If you want to lock zoom and pan, you have to do on the camera object.

**EDIT**

Otherwise you can do a screenshot of the scene in this way:

```
import maya.cmds as cmd
import maya.OpenMaya as api
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI    


def grabViewport(directory, imageName, ext="jpg"):
    viewport = apiUI.M3dView.active3dView()
    viewport.refresh()

    img = api.MImage()
    img.create(1280, 720)
    viewport.readColorBuffer(img, True)

    filePath = os.path.join(directory, imageName + "." + ext)
    img.writeToFile(filePath, ext)


cmd.viewSet(front=True)
cmd.viewFit()
filename = "image"
dir = "c:/snapshots"
ext = "jpg"
imageName = filename + "_front"
grabViewport(dir, imageName, ext)
```

So now you can take that image and set in your panel.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay but I have been sick. I just tried to follow your instructions. the mbv=false did just half the trick. I mean he hid the file - shading - lighting etc menu but not the icon menu.  Any hint? Thanks, Daniele

Comment: If you don't need the rotation of the facial_cam, a workaround might be take a screenshot of the viewport. That solve both camera lock and menu visibility

Comment: Found it: use `mel.eval("ToggleModelEditorBars")`  to toggle bar visibility

Comment: I did few test. Your way works the first time I open the window, but If I open it a second time it will appear again, and the third time not and so on. The solution is just puttin me = False in modelPanel. Unfortunately this  was still not enough because I didn't have control of the grid and Pan and Zoom. The best solution so far is using cmds.modelEditor(camera = "facial_cam", grid = False, ignorePanZoom = True). Unfortunately ignorePanZoom is not working and I have no idea why. Any clue?

Comment: Try to create first a model panel, then when you create a model editor 'assign' it that panel with the flag _panel_.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.. maybe I didn't understand what I have to do.. I did this:
FacialPanel = cmds.modelPanel()
cmds.modelEditor(camera = "facial_cam", grid = False, ignorePanZoom = True, panel = "FacialPanel")
But the result is a panel splitted between the facial cam and the perspective view.

Comment: mh.. you need to rotate facial_cam? Alternately you can do a screenshot of the viewport, that solve all of your problems. If you want I can give you a little example of how to do it.

Comment: yes please show me an example. I don't understand for screenshot of viewport.. I mean my facial_cam to stay on the facial control for my rig that I will probably hide inside the mesh...

Comment: Here is a way of how to do a screenshot:

    cmd.viewSet(front=True)
    cmd.viewFit()
    viewport = apiUI.M3dView.active3dView()
    viewport.refresh()

    img = api.MImage()
    img.create()
    viewport.readColorBuffer(img, True)

    filePath = "C:/../../image.jpg"
    img.writeToFile(filePath, "jpg")

Comment: Sorry for formatting. In cmd.viewSet() you can use flags as _top_, _persp_, _side_ to use different camera for the snapshot. With cmd.viewFit() you can fit the view with selected object (or all scene if selection is empty). Then you can set the snapshot to your panel.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do some test but I can't get it working. Maya doesn't know apiUI and all of those thing you used. Should I import something?

Comment: I write a complete example in the answer